# Form post in a new tab using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I am trying to post a form in a new window using JavaScript.

```
let form  = document.createElement('form');
form.target = 'example.com';
form.method = 'POST';

form.submit();
window.open('', form.target);
```

The above code submits the form in a new window.
This solution works fine until someone navigates to a different URL in the new tab. Let's say google.com.
On Subsequent click, **this does not work as it stays on google.com instead of posting to example.com**.

I need to post a `www-url-form-encoded` content-type in a new window and keep the reference of the tab so subsequent clicks opens the same tab if it is already opened.

Comment: "The above code submits the form in a new window". It doesn't. It submits the form on the tab it was called and then opens a new tab loading th URL of the form

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you suggest a way I can POST in a new tab and keep the reference so that new clicks reloads the form URL even if the URL is navigated?

Comment: There is no way you can make a POST request from a new tab unless you load your own hosted url where the POST request is written. One way would be creating a url on your site with post parameters and opening that url on a new tab. On that URL, add an html file which will take params from the URL and make a post request.